# How to compare strings in ksh

Tags: shell, quoting, ksh, test

I want to check the result of a job and execute an action on `FAILED`.

First: I grep the last word of the line in my application logfile (for the recent processed file (`$processedfilename`)):

```
check1=$(grep "$processedfilename" "$logfile" | grep "anotherword" | \
    grep "FAILED" | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}')
```

This results in `[FAILED]`.

Now I want to check on the result

```
if [ $check1 -eq "[[FAILED]" ] 
then
```

or

```
if [ $check1 -eq "\[FAILED]" ] 
then
```

There's always *arithmetic syntax error*.

What's the correct syntax to check on `[FAILED]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always double quote variables.  And you need `=` for string equals.  So:

```
if [ "$check1" = "[FAILED]" ]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing an arithmetic comparison by using `-eq` leading to the error, you need to do string comparison by using `=` (or `==` inside `[[`), and for that using quotes is enough:

```
[ "$check1" = "[[FAILED]" ]
[[ "$check1" = "[[FAILED]" ]]
```

Comment: NOTE `==` only works with `[[`

Comment: @AlexejMagura That is mentioned in the answer. From answer: `== (inside [[)`